# jQuery UI interfering with Show()

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I use the following code to collapse/show divs in my content page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Hookup event handlers and execute HTML DOM-related code
$('#nameHyperLink').click(function() {

        var div = $('#nameDiv');
        var link = $('#nameHyperLink');
        if (div.css('display') == 'none') {
            link.text('Hide Data');
            div.show('100');
        }
        else {
            link.text('Show Data');
            div.hide('100');
        }

    });
});
```

When I include the jquery UI script file, this code no longer works.  The text for the hyperlink changes, but the div is not actually displayed.

Why is this?

Comment: make sure that you inlcude the ui file after the jquery file.

Comment: @Matthew - What does `div.show(100);` do?

Comment: @Sarfraz the ui file is included after the jquery file.

Comment: @Nick it reveals the target div (by setting `display:block` or `display:inline` depending on what it originally was) in 100 ms by fading in.

Comment: @Matthew - I meant try it without the quotes :)

Comment: @Nick that worked!  Do you know why?  Post that as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @Matthew - See the answer below, and link inside for more details, we had to track this sucker down a little over a month ago :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're seeing here is a result of the [removal/change of some code in jQuery UI 1.8](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/1-8rc2-toggle-speed-issue).  Previously, and still in core, any unrecognized string passed to hide/show defaults to the "normal" speed.

For more details, you can see a similar question here: [jQuery 1.4.2 - is $("#foo").hide("normal") broken or am I crazy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578204/jquery-1-4-2-is-foo-hidenormal-broken-or-am-i-crazy)

Comment: @karim79 I haven't tested, is this still broken in 1.8.1 released the other day?

Comment: I don't know. I changed all `hide("normal")`s to `slideUp()`, plus I was unaware of the update!

Comment: @karim79 - Still broken :( http://jsfiddle.net/LjKy4/ This was *really* a crap move by whoever committed that change.

Comment: That's insane. At this rate we're going to have to develop a show/hide compatibility patch.